# Converting a Canvas prototype to iOS native

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, cocoa, canvas

I have developed a Canvas prototype of a game (kind of), and even though I have it running at a decent 30 FPS in a desktop browser, the performance on iOS devices is not what I hoped (lots of unavoidable pixel-level manipulation in nested x/y loops, already optimized as far as possible).

So, I'll have to convert it to a mostly native ObjC app.
I have no knowledge of ObjC or Cocoa Touch, but a solid generic C background. Now, I guess I have two options -- can anyone recommend one of them and whether they are at all possible?

1) Put the prototype into a UIWebView, and JUST do the pixel buffer filling loops in C. Can I get a pointer to a Canvas pixel array living in a web view "into C", and would I be allowed to write to it?

2) Make it all native. The caveat here is that I use quite a few 2D drawing functions too (bezierCurveTo etc.), and I wouldn't want to recode those, or find drawing libraries. So, is there a Canvas-compatible drawing API available in iOS that can work outside a web view?

Comment: For some odd reason recommending http://impactjs.com/ejecta was rejected as an answer but I think is something worth considering

Answer (score 0):

> Put the prototype into a UIWebView, and JUST do the pixel buffer filling loops in C

Nah. Then just embed a web view into your app and continue coding in JavaScript. It's already JITted so you don't really have to worry about performance.

> Can I get a pointer to a Canvas pixel array living in a web view "into C"

No, not directly. If you are a hardcore assembly hacker and reverse engineer, then you may be able to do it by looking at the memory layout and call stack of a `UIWebView` drawing to a canvas, but it's just nonsense.

> and would I be allowed to write to it?

Once you program your way down to that, I'm sure you would.

> Make it all native.

If you wish so...

> The caveat here is that I use quite a few 2D drawing functions too (bezierCurveTo etc.), and I wouldn't want to recode those, or find drawing libraries.

You wouldn't have to do either of those, instead you could just read the documentation of the **uber awsum graphix libz** called [CoreGraphics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html). It comes by default with iOS (as well as OS X, for the record).

> So, is there a Canvas-compatible drawing API available in iOS that can work outside a web view?

No, I don't know of one.

Comment: According to what I've read on various sites, a web view is not JITted due to security concerns...

Comment: @user1364098 I'll have to search for some kind of proof or disproof I think.

Comment: @user1364098 Indeed, the [daring fireball says](http://daringfireball.net/2011/03/nitro_ios_43) it's available in MobileSafari only. Stupid Apple. ***Stupid Apple!*** Then, if you are looking forward to make it all native, as I mentioned, you'd better go the Core Graphics way. It's the API that resembles HTML & JavaScript's `<canvas>` the most.

Comment: Yeah, from a quick glance at the API docs, that looks very similar to Canvas - seems like most stuff can even be converted using Regex replace. Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

Translating your objective c code to html5 sounds like a daunting task,   How about a 3rd option where you don't have to change your JavaScript code ?

http://impactjs.com/ejecta

> Ejecta is like a Browser without the Browser. It's specially crafted
>   for Games and Animations. It has no DIVs, no Tables, no Forms – only
>   Canvas and Audio elements. This focus makes it fast.

Yes, it's open source

https://github.com/phoboslab/Ejecta